# Cannot recognise a chinese chracter handwriting

Tags: meaning, traditional-characters, character-identification, writing

[image]

Can anyone else tell me what the last character is please?[image]

Comment: Could you post the text around them as well?

Comment: You should give some context. Here’s a guess: 右同此 (*...right side, same as this*).

Comment: Added a larger image. This is the largest one ive got. Thanks for help guys.

Comment: Wow. Beautiful handwriting. Too bad people write with their hands so rarely nowadays...

Comment: @AndriyMakukha Really? It seems not to me.

Comment: @TooskyHierot, I love Chinese calligraphy and handwritten characters in general. It looks creative and artistic, unlike the standard fonts.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha It looks like the writer practicing calligraphy, for the right column doesn't form a meaningful sentence.

Comment: Is it a list of properties?

Comment: Yes, it is something like that. Probably a housing contract. I doubt it was for practising calligraphy. Couldn't find anyone who could tell which character that is unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Chinese handwriting and calligraphy tradition allow for huge variability in appearance of characters.

With these three characters, first two are easily identified as 右 and 同. (Though the writer smooshes together the strokes of the mouth 口 part and the result resembles cursive letter *n*, yet his strokes clearly follow the right order.) For comparison, here are possible appearances of these characters from the *Compilation of Cursive Characters*《草字彙》:

[image: 右 and 同，from 草字彙]

As for the third character, the right part quite clearly identifies as 匕, which got transformed into S-like or b-like stroke crossed by a checkmark-like stroke. According to the cursive character compilation《草字彙》, this transformation is a typical one for this radical:

[image: 匕，from 草字彙]

That leaves us with only a few characters that have 匕 on the right, like 比 (compare)，北 (north)，此 (this)，化 (chemistry), as well as more rare characters like 牝 (female animal), 叱 (shout), 吡，妣，秕，舭。Only 此 seems to make sense with the preceding characters.   Moreover, I checked database of old cursive characters, and variants of 此 resemble what you have here most closely:

[image: 此，from 王羲之書法字典]

So, in conclusion, I think this is most likely 右同此.

Answer (score 0):

### Just provide a guess: ‘学’.

Combined with the other two characters you give in the first image, you can get a phrase “右同学”, which means "Student You".

And I recognized a place name in the larger image you give: “高敞郡新林面新坪里”(starting from the fourth in the upper right corner), in English is "Sinpyeong-ri, Sinlim-myeon, Kochang-gun", a South Korean place name.

> However, it's **weird** to see someone wrote a phrase like “右同学” in calligraphy writing. So, maybe my inference just go wrong.

Comment: According to my cursive character database, cursive versions of 学 (學) don't look anything like this.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha Well, maybe you are right, I am less confident with my guess now. 